# Is it possible to change the input type of a parameter inside a SqlDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, sqldatasource

I created a table using a Sqldatasource in .net webforms. I added a "commandField" that allows you to edit and update the content of this table, but by default the input type is "text". I would like to have different input types for some columns. For example the description column should be a "textarea" and the category column should be a "select dropdown".

I tried editing the input type= text in CSS, but this was a failure. Apparently only the textarea input type allows multiple lines to be displayed for the user.

This is how I'm calling the edit column in the table:

```
<asp:CommandField  ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-BackColor="DarkOrange" ControlStyle-CssClass="trCBPad" ItemStyle-CssClass="flex-container2"  HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True">
<ControlStyle BackColor="DarkOrange" CssClass="trCBPad"></ControlStyle>
```

This is the dataField I would like to edit, so that the input is a textarea:

```
<asp:BoundField  DataField="ProofPointId" HeaderText="ProofPointId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProofPointId" />
```

Comment: Are you talking about changing a `gridview`? If so, search for changing a bound field to `templatefield`.

Comment: You have to make a Detail Section first. Then you can create the Edit Menu as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If yor are using a gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  DataSourceId="MyDataSource"  DataKeyNames="Code"
AutoGenerateColumns="false"       AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"   runat="server">
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Eval("Name")%>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>' runat="server" />
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Description">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Eval("Description")%>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Multiline" ID="txtDesctiption"Text='<%# Bind("Description")%>'   
runat="server" />
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```